# Injecting into a class library with Ninject, where the constructor takes multiple arguments

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am in the midst of a Ninject dilema. Moreso, how to bind from multiple areas in my C# solution to the same container. In all, I know that loading via Ninject Modules is the best way to do this, but I won't be able to access the kernel directly (which is as I understand it, an Anti-Pattern anyway) to make calls to `_kernel.Get<T>()`.

So it is my belief that constructor injection is the best way to go. Now suppose I have the top level class `Program`, which loads the `Module : NinjectModule` class

```
class Program
{
    IKernel _kernel;
    public static main()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        _kernel.Load(ClassA.Module);
        _kernel.Load(ClassB.Module);

    }
}
```

To keep code to a minimum, suppose ClassA modules tied all implementations of `ISomething` to `ConcreteSomething`, and `ClassB` (of which `ClassA` is dependant upon) implements the following constructor method;

```
public ClassB(ISomething thing, int paramA, int paramB)
{
    //Do stuff with paramA and paramB using thing
}
```

In a single solution, the _kernel could be accessed directly, and `_kernel.Get<ClassB>.WithConstructorArgument("paramA", 123).WithCon...`

However, I am uncertain as to how this would work where the providing class has no access to its callers container.

One thought that crossed my mind would be by using a factory method, but I have no idea how this would work.

Any weight would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are the values of paramA, paramB (ctor of ClassB) coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use constructor injections for dependencies.

How about moving the parameters (paramA, paramB) to a method, like Initialize or Execute?

If that is not reasonable (like when its command), then you will need to use a factory.
Have a look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory.

For use cases not supported by the factory extension, you can always have a factory which gets IResolutionRoot injected. You can do the Get<> on that interface. The factory can reside in any assembly.

```
public class FactoryB : IFactoryB {
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;
    public FactoryB(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot) {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IClassB Create(int paramA, int paramB) {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IClassB>(new ConstructorArgument("paramA", paramA), new ConstructorArgument("paramB", paramB));
    }
}
```

I wonder however, whether you really need to use a factory for paramA, paramB. This dependends on where the values are coming from / how they are determined. Are they dependent upon classA or are they rather just "global configuration" values?

Comment: In my case these parameters will be cascading down from the composition root (i.e: `Program` aka GUI client), however, I may need to use some elements from the middle library (`ClassA` in this case). In my case, I have a RESTful PCL which needs a specific hash/crypto algorithm passed down for specific platforms. The platform declaration will be made in the composition root (`Client.{platform}`) and passed to a core client library shared across all platforms. This then makes calls to the PCL, injecting the specific `IHash` cryptographic hash in.

Comment: In this case it should be easy to bind `IHash` in the composition root (`Client.{platform}`) and define the rest in the middle library (`ClassA`). You might want to think about convention-based module loading so you do need to configure as little as possible in your `Client.{platform}` composition root.

Comment: I had to abandon IoC at the moment as we needed to release a minimum viable product. There was quite a few tightly coupled classes that needed some extensive work in the core client library (and a heap of PCL woes) but I will take note of this suggestion when the rewrite comes in the next few weeks.